# How can I move a project that includes images-as-planes?

Tags: workflow, windows

I am working on a project that includes images-as-planes.  I would like to copy the whole project to another computer.  How can I move the Blender file and also relocate the image-as-planes source PNGs without the Blender animation file losing track of where to find the PNGs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pack all external data into the blend file by clicking on "File → External Data → Pack into .blend file"

Comment: Thanks!  Would that make playback speed faster as well?

Answer (score 2):

By default blender tries to keep external data (images, textures, fonts, libraries, etc.) with relative paths, so if you have a project folder and all your external files are kept in it, you should be able to copy/move the whole folder and take it with you anywhere, and blender would still find your libraries, as long as you keep your sub folder structure intact.

Packing should have no noticeable lasting impact on performance, except maybe on file reading or loading for the first time.