# How to pack images into blend file

Tags: blend-files

Is there a way to pack all my images into the blend file so I can transfer it more easily?

I'm using the version 2.8

Comment: I hope nothing bad happened to you  :/

Comment: Search for "Pack External Data"

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47576/how-can-i-move-a-project-that-includes-images-as-planes

Comment: thank u all for helping me

Answer (score 13):

You can use the *Pack All Into .blend* function. Open the project, go to **File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend**, and wait for the packing of your images/textures (it depends on how many textures you used in your project). Then save again the file (maybe with a different name, e.g. *project_packed*). So when you open the file on a different computer, you don't have to re-loading the textures.

[image]

Comment: thank u so much for helping me