# Pack PNG Sequence in Blend File

Tags: packed-data

Can anyone point me in a direction towards learning WHY you can't pack PNG sequences in a blend file? I know that you can't... But it seems like it would be an easy feature to add. Thanks!

Comment: Because it would easily balloon file sizes into unreadable scales, requiring huge amounts of memory and risking potential data corruption

Comment: You can look at using [BAT](https://developer.blender.org/project/profile/79/) to pack up all your files for transport.

Answer (score -1):

From what I've read you can add pngs as texture information after they are rendered and then [Select the Pack All option to save the png with the blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139054/how-to-pack-images-into-blend-file/139055).

But why do you want it to all travel together? Normally the objective of rendering is to get the images out of Blender so that you can use them on your website or something.

Comment: An image sequence does not have to mean the final rendered images. You can use an image sequence as an animated texture, these should get packed the same as any image texture.

Comment: You can do it, but the blend file might get really big.