# Mask and convert color in photo/video

Tags: compositing-nodes, color, masking, chromakey

I am very new to blender still.  I want to simply change the color of an object in the video.  I want to know if there is good way to do this.  I am including what I have to test.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI images used in the project are not saved in the .blend file. They have to be packed. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139054/how-to-pack-images-into-blend-file

Comment: I updated the OP with the packed file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want.

Here are a few ideas:

- Use a hue correct node, where you can select the color very precisely and change the hue (or saturation).

  [image]
- Use a chroma key to create a matte and then use that information to combine two differently colored versions of the same image.

  [image]
- Or use a mask to control the mix.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds like I was on the right path using a mask and chroma key to keep the color changes localized on the specific object.   thx

Comment: Use the masks as factor to mix elements, the only difference is that some can be created automatically for you and some you draw yourself, but the function is the same.