# 'Pack into Blend' doesn't include .Mov Files

Tags: packed-data

brand new to blender, having jumped ship from Davinci Resolve/Fusion in order to make a music video in a 3d environment.

Loving the workflow so far, but have hit on one big snag straight away.

The prototype project I have consists of some .PNGs mapped onto surfaces along with a Prores 444 format .mov file (its green-screened/Alpha-Channel footage).

Despite checking the 'Pack into blend' option, whenever I ltransfer the project onto a separate Mac, the Video element is missing. I've of course copied over the video file into the same directory path on the 2nd machine, but I can't figure out how to get blender to relink. I just get a blank block where there should be the video of a singer.

Hopefully someone can help a newbie ! Lots of previous experience with Resolve, Premiere, FCPX, pro Tools etc...just a bit stuck with data management here. The final music video will have around 200 elements that will be imported , so keen to get the asset management correct at this stage.

All help appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

### Mov files can't currently be packed

As said in the manual at the [Packed Data page:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/blend/packed_data.html?highlight=packing)

> Some typically heavy external files, like video ones from the Sequence
>   Editor or Movie Clips, cannot be packed in a blend-file.

Your file fall into the Movie clips category, which unfortunately has been exclude from the files format that can be packed. You'll have to copy between folders and update the path.

If you are using an "image as plane", you should browse in the shader editor the image sequence node and change the path from the Open Image icon:

[image]

Comment: Hi Carlo, thanks for the reply. If a 'heavy' file like a .mov can't be packed, how do I make it re-link on the new machine? Ive copied the .mov file (144meg) over to the same directory as my blender file, but it doesn't automatically relink. How do I relink it? Cheers !

Comment: What are you using your .mov file for? In a material? In the sequance editor? In the Movie clip editor?

Comment: Hi Carlo, its '2d section of film' playing inside a 3d environment. It was imported into the project using the 'import images as planes' add-on if that helps .

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47576/how-can-i-move-a-project-that-includes-images-as-planes/47586#47586 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/moving-all-files-to-a-new-computer-my-concern-is-links/56689#56689