# Is there a way to pack miscellaneous files into a .blend?

Tags: packing

I would like to pack a Gimp ".xcf" file into a .blend file, rather than create a zip that includes this file, for example to include it in a blender.stackexchange answer via https://blend-exchange.com/.   But there does not appear to be a way to link or refer to files that blender specifically doesn't recognize in something like an Image Texture node.  I suppose I could "fake out" blender by renaming the file suffix, include a Text note about how to find this file, etc, but perhaps I'm missing a more direct way to pack a miscellaneous file into .blend, to be uploaded by https://blend-exchange.com/ that only recognized .blend files.

Perhaps this is for security reasons?  I see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150564/pack-into-blend-doesnt-include-mov-files), which might give me my answer, but doesn't give any blender product reasoning.

Comment: Back in the old days of telnet and basically only text transfer, a binary file was  converted to text. Could be an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The [Packed Data manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/files/blend/packed_data.html) specifically points out that

> Not all external files can be packed

You can only pack files that are used in the blend file, like image files associated with image textures, or UVs.  In particular you can't pack files that are image files in formats that Blender doesn't understand.

Comment: Mountain View, CA !  --- Stanford grad of '79 here.