# How do I move a blend file and its textures to a different PC?

Tags: texturing, image

I created an Architecture model and want move it to a other PC.
But the blend file cant find my textures once it's moved.

If I create a texture folder and insert the new path, it shows the textures but without normals and roughness because I'm insert new paths for it too.

What is best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can pack the textures into the project before transferring it to the other computer. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39257/packing-texture-files-in-a-single-blend-file

Comment: holy cow, thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/moving-all-files-to-a-new-computer-my-concern-is-links/56689#56689 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47576/how-can-i-move-a-project-that-includes-images-as-planes/47586#47586