How do I reconnect image to a Blender project
I Have a Blender project that I  saved to a USB but that contains reference images and image texture. The image appear normal on my own computer but every time I use a different computer the Imager turns a bright purple colour.  I don't know why the Image I'm using are on the USB.
How do I get the image to appear normal

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56683/moving-all-files-to-a-new-computer-my-concern-is-links/56689#56689 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47576/how-can-i-move-a-project-that-includes-images-as-planes/47586#47586
